problem using pthread_cond_signal and pthread_cond_timedwait
I have a small program with two threads sending signal to each other.
The program first works as expected but stop after various runs as the pthread_cond_timedwait run into a timeout.
For my test I stop the program if one thread is running into a timeout.
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex1;
pthread_cond_t cond1;
pthread_mutex_t mutex2;
pthread_cond_t cond2;
bool run = true;

void signal_handler(int sig_num) { run = false; }

void* thread1(void* arg) {
    struct timespec ts;
    struct timeval now;
    uint32_t runs = 0;

    while (run) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);

        gettimeofday(&now, NULL);
        ts.tv_sec = now.tv_sec + 1;
        ts.tv_nsec = now.tv_usec * 1000;
        
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex2);
        int result = pthread_cond_timedwait(&cond2, &mutex2, &ts);
        if (result == ETIMEDOUT) {
            printf("Thread 1: Wait timed out\n");
            run = false;
        } else if (result == 0) {
            //  printf("Thread 1: Signal received from Thread 2\n");
            if (pthread_cond_signal(&cond1) != 0) {
                printf("Failed to signal cond1\n");
            }
            runs++;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex2);
    }

    printf("T1: runs=%d\n", runs);
    return NULL;
}

void* thread2(void* arg) {
    struct timespec ts;
    struct timeval now;
    uint32_t runs = 0;

    while (run) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex2);

        gettimeofday(&now, NULL);
        ts.tv_sec = now.tv_sec + 1;
        ts.tv_nsec = now.tv_usec * 1000;

        // printf("Thread 2: Sending signal to Thread 1\n");
        if (pthread_cond_signal(&cond2) != 0) {
            printf("Failed to signal cond2\n");
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex2);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
        int result = pthread_cond_timedwait(&cond1, &mutex1, &ts);
        if (result == ETIMEDOUT) {
            printf("Thread 2: Wait timed out\n");
            run = false;
        } else {
            runs++;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
    }

    printf("T2: runs=%d\n", runs);

    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t tid1, tid2;

    signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
    signal(SIGTERM, signal_handler);

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex1, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&cond1, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex2, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&cond2, NULL);

    pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, thread1, NULL);
    pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, thread2, NULL);

    pthread_join(tid1, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid2, NULL);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex1);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&cond1);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex2);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&cond2);

    return 0;
}


This end in the following output:
$ /tmp/test 
Thread 2: Wait timed out
T2: runs=84498
Thread 1: Wait timed out
T1: runs=84499

$ /tmp/test
Thread 2: Wait timed out
T2: runs=148
Thread 1: Wait timed out
T1: runs=148


But I expect it to run forever or until I kill it.

You can absolutely do that with a mutex and CV and some shared state, but for this particular task I would probably choose a pair of semaphores instead.

You're misusing pthread_cond_timedwait.
You might believe a cond var "becomes signaled" until something waits for it. That's not the case. While one can signal a cond var, it doesn't become signaled. Cond vars have no state. When you signal a cond var, it wakes up a waiter if there is one (or all of them in the case of pthread_cond_broadcast). If there are no waiters at the time, signaling a cond var does nothing.
This means you can't wait for the cond var to become signaled. If you attempt to use this model, it will fail when the signal arrives before the intended recipient starts waiting. This must be what's happening here.
pthread_cond_wait and pthread_cond_timedwait are used to wait for an external condition. The proper flow looks something like the following:
Signalee
pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex );

while ( run && !external_condition() ) {
   if ( errno = pthread_cond_timedwait( &cond, &mutex, &ts ) ) {
      perror( "pthread_cond_timedwait" );
      run = false;
   }
}

pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex );

Signaler
pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex );

possibly_make_external_condition_true();
pthread_cond_signal( &cond );   // Doesn't need to be in the mutex.

pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex );


You didn't specify what you are trying to achieve, but I think you want to have thread1 add one to its run, then have thread2 do the same, and repeat. This is very sequential code for which threads makes no sense, but let's call it a learning exercise.
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 2

typedef struct {
   unsigned idx;
   pthread_t tid;
   unsigned runs;
} ThreadData;

ThreadData thread_datas[ NUM_THREADS ];

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t  cond  = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

// Shared variables access-controlled by `mutex`.
unsigned turn = 0;

// Shared variables access-controlled using atomics.
atomic_bool abort_program = false;


static void signal_handler( int signum ) {
   (void)signum;
   abort_program = true;
   pthread_cond_broadcast( &cond );
}


static void *thread( void *arg ) {
   ThreadData *thread_data = arg;

   thread_data->runs = 0;

   pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex );

   while ( 1 ) {
      // Wait for my turn.
      {
         struct timeval now;
         struct timespec ts;
         gettimeofday( &now, NULL );
         ts.tv_sec = now.tv_sec + 1;
         ts.tv_nsec = now.tv_usec * 1000;

         while ( !abort_program && turn != thread_data->idx ) {
            if ( errno = pthread_cond_timedwait( &cond, &mutex, &ts ) ) {
               fprintf( stderr, "thread%u: pthread_cond_timedwait: %s\n", thread_data->idx, strerror( errno ) );
               abort_program = true;
            }
         }
      }

      // Abort?
      if ( abort_program ) {
         fprintf( stderr, "thread%u: Aborting.\n", thread_data->idx );
         break;
      }

      // Take our turn.
      ++thread_data->runs;
      if ( thread_data->runs <= 10 || thread_data->runs % 10000 == 0 )
         printf( "thread%u: runs = %u\n", thread_data->idx, thread_data->runs );

      // Let another thread know it's its turn.
      turn = ( turn + 1 ) % NUM_THREADS;
      pthread_cond_signal( &cond );
   }

   pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex );

   return thread_data;
}


int main( void ) {
   {
      struct sigaction sa;
      sa.sa_handler = signal_handler;
      sigemptyset( &sa.sa_mask );
      sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
      sigaction( SIGINT,  &sa, NULL );
      sigaction( SIGTERM, &sa, NULL );
   }

   for ( unsigned i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i ) {
      ThreadData *thread_data = &( thread_datas[ i ] );
      thread_data->idx = i;
      pthread_create( &( thread_data->tid ), NULL, thread, thread_data );
   }

   for ( unsigned i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i ) {
      ThreadData *thread_data = &( thread_datas[ i ] );
      pthread_join( thread_data->tid, NULL );
   }

   for ( unsigned i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i ) {
      ThreadData *thread_data = &( thread_datas[ i ] );
      printf( "thread%u: Final runs = %u\n", thread_data->idx, thread_data->runs );
   }

   return 0;
}

$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pthread a.c -o a && ./a
thread0: runs = 1
thread1: runs = 1
thread0: runs = 2
thread1: runs = 2
thread0: runs = 3
thread1: runs = 3
thread0: runs = 4
thread1: runs = 4
thread0: runs = 5
thread1: runs = 5
thread0: runs = 6
thread1: runs = 6
thread0: runs = 7
thread1: runs = 7
thread0: runs = 8
thread1: runs = 8
thread0: runs = 9
thread1: runs = 9
thread0: runs = 10
thread1: runs = 10
thread0: runs = 10000
thread1: runs = 10000
thread0: runs = 20000
thread1: runs = 20000
thread0: runs = 30000
thread1: runs = 30000
^Cthread0: Aborting.
thread1: Aborting.
thread0: Final runs = 32424
thread1: Final runs = 32423

Notes (in no particular order):

pthread_mutex_init and pthread_cond_init were replaced with PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER and PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER initializers since the situation permitted it.
signal was replaced with the recommended sigaction.
Blocking functions interrupted by signals are now automatically restarted.
Errors are now sent to stderr.
Thread-specific data is now used instead of multiple copies of what is essentially the same function.
The signal handler now signals the cond var, avoiding the need to poll abort_program (formerly called run) by timing out the wait.
This also means the waits will never time out. The "work" being done is simply too little. A pthread_cond_timedwait could be replaced with pthread_cond_wait.
Error checking should be added for pthread_create. The other calls for which error checking is missing shouldn't fail unless an invalid argument is provided.
By assigning the value returned by pthread functions to errno, we don't need another variable, and we can use perror and similar.


Updated. ______
